# C++/C Multiple threads to read gz file simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading, zlib, compression, deflate

I am attempting to read a gzip-compressed file from multiple threads.

I was thinking this would significantly speed up decompression process as my `gzread` functions in multiple threads start from different file offset (using `gseek`), hence they read different parts of the file.

The simplified code is like

```
// in threads
auto gf = gzopen("file.gz",xxx);
gzseek(gf,offset);
gzread(xx);
gzclose(gf);
```

To my surprise, my multi-thread version program does **not** speed up at all. The 20-thread version uses exactly the same time as the single-thread version. I am pretty sure this is far away from the disk bottleneck.

I guess the zlib inflation functionality may need to decompress the entire file for reading even a small part, but I failed to get any clue from their manual.

Anyone have an idea how to speed up in my case?

Comment: Usually most of the time is spend in data reading. Not in decompression. Put your data on the fastest available media and try again.

Comment: @GMichael Thanks for the clue. I did experiment for that in which I ran the same program for two compressed files, one with higher compressed level of size 600M, the other with lower level but of size 2G. The first file took 22s while the latter used 10s. So it is more likely due to the decompression.

Comment: Maybe try to use same file handles in each thread and not open it separately

Comment: @fandin If this is the case, check the load on CPU. You should see all CPUs used to have benefit in performance. By the way, do not open too many threads. Context switching takes time.

Comment: @V.Kravchenko  I believe that is too dangerous as I used gzseek.

Comment: @GMichael   I was testing it on a 20 core empty-load server. I did see the cpu usage from top. The program really takes 20 cores.

Comment: @fanbin Try then copy `gf` structure for every thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: zlib isn't designed for random access. [It seems possible to implement](http://lh3.github.io/2014/07/05/random-access-to-zlib-compressed-files/), though requiring a complete read-through to build an index, so it might not be helpful in your case.

Let's look into the [zlib source](https://github.com/madler/zlib). [gzseek](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/50893291621658f355bc5b4d450a8d06a563053d/gzlib.c#L439) is a wrapper around [gzseek64](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/50893291621658f355bc5b4d450a8d06a563053d/gzlib.c#L362), which contains:

```
/* if within raw area while reading, just go there */
if (state->mode == GZ_READ && state->how == COPY &&
        state->x.pos + offset >= 0) {
```

"Within raw area" doesn't sound quite right if we're processing a gzipped file. Let's look up the meaning of `state->how` in [gzguts.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/50893291621658f355bc5b4d450a8d06a563053d/gzguts.h#L177):

```
int how; /* 0: get header, 1: copy, 2: decompress */
```

Right. At the end of `gz_open`, a call to `gz_reset` sets `how` to 0. Returning to `gzseek64`, we end up with this modification to the state:

```
state->seek = 1;
state->skip = offset;
```

[gzread](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/50893291621658f355bc5b4d450a8d06a563053d/gzread.c#L287), when called, processes this with a call to [gz_skip](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/50893291621658f355bc5b4d450a8d06a563053d/gzread.c#L255):

```
if (state->seek) {
    state->seek = 0;
    if (gz_skip(state, state->skip) == -1)
        return -1;
}
```

Following this rabbit hole just a bit further, we find that `gz_skip` calls `gz_fetch` until `gz_fetch` has processed enough input for the desired seek. `gz_fetch`, on its first loop iteration, calls `gz_look` which sets `state->how = GZIP`, which causes `gz_fetch` to decompress data from the input. In other words, your suspicion is right: zlib does decompress the entire file up to that point when you use `gzseek`.

Comment: A textbook geek/hack example to me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: due to the serial nature of a deflate stream, `gzseek()` must decode all of the compressed data from the start up to the requested seek point. So you can't get any gain with what you are trying to do. In fact, the total cycles spent will increase with the square of the length of the compressed data! So don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

zlib implementation have no multithreading (http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq21 - "Is zlib thread-safe? - Yes. ... Of course, you should only operate on any given zlib or gzip stream from a single thread at a time.") and will decompress "entire file" up to seeked position.

And zlib format has bad alignment (bit alignment) / no offset fields ([deflate format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE#Stream_format)) to enable parallel decompression/seeking.

You may try another implementations of z (deflate/inflate), for example, http://zlib.net/pigz/  (or switch from ancient compression from the era of single core to non-zlib modern parallel formats, xz/lzma/something from google)

> pigz, which stands for parallel implementation of gzip, is a fully functional replacement for gzip that exploits multiple processors and multiple cores to the hilt when compressing data. pigz was written by Mark Adler, and uses the zlib and pthread libraries. To compile and use pigz, please read the README file in the source code distribution. You can read the [pigz manual page here.](http://zlib.net/pigz/pigz.pdf)

The manual page is http://zlib.net/pigz/pigz.pdf and it has useful information.

It uses format compatible to zlib, but adopted to parallel compress:

> Each partial raw deflate stream is terminated by an empty stored block ... in order to end that partial bit stream at a byte boundary.

Still, DEFLATE format is bad for parallel decompression:

> Decompression can’t be parallelized, at least not without specially prepared deflate streams for that purpose. Asaresult, pigz uses a single thread (the main thread) for decompression, but will create three other threads for reading, writing, and check calculation, which can speed up decompression under some circumstances.